# netbeans 7.2 svn problems

Tags: svn, netbeans, netbeans-7.2

I have a problem using subversion 1.6.12 (as server) and netbeans 7.2RC as client.
The svn server works perfectly with TortoiseSVN 1.7.7, but netbeans throw the following error:

`svn: authentication cancelled`

thanks in advance for the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you start NB as admin (if windows), does it work?

Other aspects:

- Do you have non ascii chars in your name / passwort?
- Remove your saved SVN infos (login etc.) from netbeans folder in your user profile directory (make a backup before!)